# Installing things as root and accessing those things as normal users

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, permissions

I'm new to Ubuntu and am now running 14.04 as a separate partition from Windows.

To install things I have to run `sudo apt-get` because I get permission errors otherwise. As such I use `sudo -s` to run most of the installation commands.

The problem now is that everything that I install as root will not work without root access. Stuff like `node`, `meteor`, `ipython` etc will get errors from accessing various folders.

This forces me to use root access for everything, and I am confused as to why this is the case. Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT:
For example, when trying to run `node` I get this:

```
$ node> node.js:148
          throw err;
          ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/pewpew/.node_repl_history'
at Error (native)
```

Running stat on `/home/pewpew/.node_repl_history`, I get:

```
 ~$ stat /home/pewpew/.node_repl_history 
 File: ‘/home/pewpew/.node_repl_history’


 Size: 6            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 808h/2056d  Inode: 1714569     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-11-24 09:39:11.687765710 +0800
Modify: 2015-11-24 10:19:45.959716037 +0800
Change: 2015-11-24 10:19:45.959716037 +0800
 Birth: -
```

Meteor gets a similar error when accessing `~/.meteor` folder and I used `chown` to change the owner of the folder to the non-root user.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example? An error you get with `node`, or `ipython`, for instance?

Comment: `$ node> node.js:148
                  throw err;
                  ^
    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/pewpew/.node_repl_history'
    at Error (native)`

Comment: Please, [edit] your post to add more information. And add the output of `stat /home/pewpew/.node_repl_history` too, while you're at it.

Comment: ok, tell me if there's anything else that will be helpful information and I'll edit it in

Comment: `sudo` doesn't reset `$HOME` by default. So, if these programs create/modify files in your home directory, and you run them as `sudo`, they become owned by root. When you first ran `node` or `ipython` or `meteor`, did you run from the `sudo -s` session you started?

Comment: yes i think so, is there something i should do to fix this? I was previously running everything under `sudo -s` because i was getting permission errors for everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: use `sudo` the way it is intended to be used in Ubuntu: for each command that requires it, no more. Don't use `sudo` to run a command unless it needs to be root. For example, most users would only need `sudo` for installing things.

Second: use `sudo -i` if you need a root shell. Have a look at [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35338/70524) to see the effect of various ways of getting a root shell. In particular, `sudo -i` and `sudo su -`, both of which provide login shells, give the cleanest environment.

Lastly, take back ownership of your home directory:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~
```

`~` is a shortcut for your home directory. Use `-R` so that everything in your home directory is `chown`ed back to you.

Comment: @mchid ah, thought I missed something.